Qemu GPU/Display passthrough
I want to passthrough my GPU to the QEMU Guest and it complete control of my monitor (seem as if it was the ONLY OS running)
I have tried on a laptop with only the built-in monitor and the screen just went blank.
I guess in a PC it would work if we connect the monitor directly to the GPU but I can't test it.
Questions:

Is it possible to passthrough my GPU and give control of the monitor to my guest by connecting the monitor directly to the GPU?
Is it possible to give control of my laptop monitor to the guest and passthrough my GPU?

NOTES

My laptop is runing Ubuntu Cinnamon
I'd like to specify the use of QEMU with KVM even though I think it's obvious?
I would like to NOT use any host/client applications

Similar Post
I found a question (An equivalent of Looking Glass where VM side runs Linux?) that requires a host/client application to basically have the host write the frames back. I would like to not resort to this tactic and give the guest complete control of the monitor.
EDIT:
Goal
My goal is to have a VM running as a bare-metal machine (when it comes to the monitor) while passing the GPU to that VM (Which means no monitor for the host OS => Black screen on the laptop's monitor)
Example
Imagine I want to run a Mac VM (not bare-metal) on my laptop which has linux, If I want better performance I need to either find a way to add a second GPU to my laptop.
If it is possible to display stuff to the monitor of the laptop directly from the VM I can passthrough my GPU without having a second one.
Now the constraint of not using other software (like "Looking Glass"). If i want to add different guest (like a custom OS) where the software is not available I would need to either port the software or still fall back to getting a second GPU. So if it's possible I want to avoid something like this.
NOTE 2
The question is not specific for MacOS, I just found it easier to explain with this since you can't just install it without finding drivers etc, etc.

do you have two GPUs in your laptop?

No, but the point is, I don't want to have a windowed guest, I want to give complete control of the monitor.

yeah, but you can't just rip out the PCIe device that controls a lot of the memory that your system is currently communicating with and give it to a guest.

In the case I had 2 GPUs would that be possible? to give complete control of my monitor to the guest?

It's possible but your laptop's monitor should not be connected to GPU that's inside laptop, GPU passtrough is already the default in QEMU btw, but GPU of the host not external PC like laptop.

@metablaster so if I dissasemble the laptop and disconnect the display and just use SSH and HDMI to use the laptops GPU directly to an external it should work to give the Guest complete control? I feel like I'm misunderstanding something.

I don't think you can passtrough laptop's GPU to another PC (your host), what I meant you'd need to connect laptops monitor to host's GPU if you want to use that monitor (don't know it would work). BUT, it's far easier to just RDP or VNC from your laptop into VM on your host. this way you control VM from laptop that runs on PC.

@metablaster Yes I know about RDP/VNC, I just though about performance-wise it would definitely be better to have a single GPU and passthrough to the guest to perform tasks but still be able to have display (without additional software that may not exist for some guests)

@metablaster also i think you misunderstood my question/intentions, I want to have my laptop(host) passthrough it's GPU to a QEMU(Guest) and I want QEMU to directly show stuff to my laptop's monitor instead of having other software.

@user18812922 Sorry I've re-read your question and don't get it, You said the point is, I don't want to have a windowed guest, I want to give complete control of the monitor then why not simply run the guest in full screen? it seems you don't want to see host on your monitor at all?

@metablaster I will edit the question and add my goal
